# Augmenting objects in place with extra details

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

I have a scenario where I have a list of ordered objects which I wish to augment with information from another list of objects that compose the original ordered objects. For ex:

```
class Ledger {
   int id;
   List<Book> books; // ordered collection of books
   List<PricedBook> pricedBooks; //empty originally
}

class PriceLedger {
   int id;
   Set<PricedBook> booksWithPrices;
}

class Book {
   int id;
   String text;
}

class PricedBook {
   Book book;
   double price;

   public PricedBook (final Book book, double price) {
      this.book = book;
      this.price = price;
   }
}
```

So, given a `List<Ledger>` and a `List<PriceLedger>`, I want to have an output of `List<Ledger>` which contains a filled out pricedBooks collection respecting the original order of the books found in `List<Book>` but with the augmented price information from a corresponding (id = same) PriceLedger

```
public List<Ledger> augment(List<Ledger> input, List<PriceLedger> metadata)
{
    List<Ledger> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Ledger l : input)
    {
        result.add(augmentLedger(l, metadata));
    }
}

public Ledger augmentLedger(Ledger input, List<PriceLedger> metadata)
{
    List<PricedBook> result = new ArrayList<>();

    List<PricedBook> pricedBooks = metadata.stream().map(PriceLedger::booksWithPrices).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collections.toList());
    for (int i = 0; i < input.books.size(); i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pricedBooks.size(); j++) {
            if (input.books[i] == pricedBooks[j].book) {
                result.add(pricedBooks[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    Ledger l = new Ledger().setPricedBooks(result)
    return l;
}
```

The design is clearly not correct (why hold books + pricedBooks in the first place in Ledger?) but this is to just illustrate a larger problem. My attempt at a solution in also super inefficient since I am iterating over all the metadata books for each book I am attempting to augment

Comment: PricedBook should extend Book instead of having it as parameter to begin with

Comment: I'm using composition here but yes it could also be done like that. Though, just for the sake of this exercise, I would like to ignore any obvious design mistakes and focus on trying to find an efficient solution

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Why is that `augment` method still blank? *I want to have an output* is a desire and SO is not the correct place to put it up.

Comment: @nullpointer I tried the brute force solution which ive tried to describe above

Comment: @JohnBaum I still don't see that try in the question. I hope you understand [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @nullpointer added an attempt

Answer (score 1):

I assume quite a lot of things here... but the main important one is that this `input.books[i] == pricedBooks[j].book` is wrong that that you actually want to compare `PricedBook` and `Book` by their `id`s - this is probably once change that is a must here.

First I compute the `map` that I will perform look-ups against, this is the same for every value of the input, so needs to be computed only once:

```
    // PriceLedger::Id --> [ PricedBook::Id, PricedBook ]
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, PricedBook>> map = metadata.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    PriceLedger::getId,
                    pl -> pl.getBooksWithPrices().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    pb -> pb.getBook().getId(),
                                    Function.identity()))));
```

Once this is in place, its actually fairly easy to do the rest. For each `Ledger` do a lookup in the map for the corresponding `PriceLedger`; and then for each book search for the corresponding `PriceBook`.
Introducing a `Map` should speed things up quite a bit, since we are performing only a hash-lookup; instead of iterating to find the entry needed.

```
 input.stream()
            .map(l -> {
                List<Book> withoutPrice = l.getBooks();
                List<PricedBook> withPrice = withoutPrice.stream()
                        .map(b -> {
                            return map.get(l.getId()).get(b.getId());
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return new Ledger(l.getId(), l.getBooks(), withPrice);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```